# Selected Page number is getting reset in Server Side Pagination for JQuery Datatables

Tags: jquery, pagination, datatables

Below is my datatable initialization for Server Side Pagination. I am setting recordsTotal and recordsFiltered in my response with total number of records. In my ajax url I am passing page number and number of records that needs to be fetched. Datatable is loaded properly with initially 10 records in first page and total number of page count.

```
function fetchProduct(){
    var restAPICall = //passing page number and number of rows per page in url 

     $('#table').DataTable( {
                "serverSide": true, 
                "ajax": {
                    url: restAPICall,
                    dataType: "json", 
                    dataSrc: function(data){
                        return data.products;
                    },
                    dataFilter: function(data){
                            var json = jQuery.parseJSON( data );
                            json.recordsTotal = json.totalRecords;
                            json.recordsFiltered = json.totalRecords;
                            json.data = json.products;
                            return JSON.stringify( json );
                        },
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "product.productType" },
                    { "data": "product.displayName" },
                    { "data": "product.id" },
                    { "data": "product.brandName" },                
            } );
}
```

Next, when I am clicking a page number suppose 4 or 5, I am again making the ajax call and loading my datatable with currently fetched records.

```
$('#table').on('page.dt', function() {
        var info = table.page.info();
        var currentPageNo = info.page+1;            

        fetchProduct();
    });
```

**Issue:** My problem is when I am selecting a particular page then I am getting new data sets for that page but the pagination is getting reset to page no. 1 everytime.

Please help me to achieve the pagination to work properly in this scenario ? Can we restrict the pagination refresh when I am clicking a page number ? Or can we reset it back to whatever page number I have previously selected?

Comment: You don't need to recreate `$('#table').DataTable(..)` all the time. You only need it once so you don't "reset" to page 1 each time. And once your datatable is created, you can use Firefox Web Developer tool to see what params and values are sent and received so you can handle your data properly.

Comment: @KarloKokkak I am recreating datatable on page number click event to display the table as per the selected page number that I am passing in my ajax call. Is there a way to refresh only the datatable and not the pagination so that the selected page number remain unchanged.

Comment: You don't have to pass the page number and number of records in your url. Datatable already passes them on its own when you click a page number, sort and when you make any action. Use Firefox Web Developer tool to see what params and values are sent and received by the plugin.

Comment: You can refer to or/and use this very basic template: https://github.com/onwhim/jquery-datatables-template

Comment: @KarloKokkak Yes checked in Web Developer Tool, datatable is passing the required information on page number click, Thanks! Here my question is if I am not sending the number of records parameter in the url then the ajax call fetches the total number of records which again increases the processing time, then whats the point of server side pagination ?

Comment: When you click on a page number, datatables sends to your PHP file `start` and `length` parameters. You use those two in your sql's LIMIT clause, as in `LIMIT start, length`. So you don't send all data to the client, you only send that corresponds to the current page number.

Comment: @KarloKokkak As we already have our API's built, we don't want to change anything in API. When I am passing the page number and no. of records attribute in API call on click of page number, I am getting the updated data and displayed in datatable. Only issue is that pagination is also getting reset as we are initializing datatable for ajax call. Is there a way to apply "current" css class to the selected page number when datatable reloads ?? Please help.